# Maximum pollcount for poll()?

Tags: linux, sockets, polling

I have a server that handles multiple sockets from a single process.  It used to run on AIX, and I've recently ported it to linux.  Anyway, on AIX I had a #define for the maximumn number of sockets I would support set at 2000, and it works fine.

When I do that on linux, poll() fails with errno=22 (invalid argument) - presumably the pollcount parameter.  When I set this to 1000, it works fine.  So, am I just out of luck - limited to 1000 (or 1024, which is what sysconf(_SC_OPEN_MAX) returns).  Or is there something I can tune to up this limit.

1024 would probably work for the most part, but that's pretty close to the number of simultaneous users routinely on the system.

Answer (score 1):

The Linux [man page for `poll()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) says

> ERRORS
> EINVAL The nfds value exceeds the RLIMIT_NOFILE value.

`RLIMIT_NOFILE` is also the maximum number of file descriptors the process can have open at once. Check what your limit is set to, it's `ulimit -n` in the shell, and `LimitNOFILE` in systemd.

Comment: Thanks.  ulimit -n does report 1024.   I was asking how to up that limit though, but it turns out that it's as simple as putting 'ulimit -n 4094' in .bashrc.  I think 4096 is a hard limit that may be trickier to increase.  Is that true?  If so, do you know how to do it?

Comment: @littlenoodles, yeah, raising the limit depends on the environment you're running in. From the command line, `ulimit -n` works, up to the hard limit (`ulimit -Hn`) unless you're root. The limits for the shell session may come from `/etc/security/limits.conf` (via PAM). But at some point you might want to have the server launch from systemd, and to set the limits there. Of course, if the server itself starts as root, it could just call `setrlimit()` itself.

Comment: Thanks.  4096 is probably enough for now, but good to know there are ways to go higher.

Comment: Fun fact. The kernel hard limit is 1024 * 1024 ; root can't exceed it without recompiling the kernel.